# Does asymmetric fraction of finite groups tend to $0$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, pr.probability, finite-groups, automorphism-groups

Let’s define asymmetric fraction of a finite group $G$ as the number $$\mathrm{af}(G) = \frac{|\{(g, a) \in G \times \mathrm{Aut}(G)\mid a(g) = g\}|}{|G|\cdot|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|}.$$ Equivalently it can be defined as $\mathrm{P}(A(X) = X)$, where $A$ and $X$ are independent uniformly distributed random elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and $G$ respectively.

> Is it true, that $$\forall \epsilon > 0,\; \exists N \in \mathbb{N},\; \forall G \big((\lvert\,G\,\rvert > n) \to (\mathrm{af}(G) < \epsilon)\big)?$$

I know, that $$\mathrm{af}(C_{p^n}) = \dfrac{p^n + \Sigma_{i = 1}^n  p^ip^{n - 1 - i}(p - 1)}{p^{2n - 1}(p - 1)} = \dfrac{(np - n + 1)}{p^n(p - 1)}$$ and, that $$\mathrm{af}(G) \leq \frac{1}{2} + \dfrac{|\{g \in G\mid \forall a \in \mathrm{Aut}(G), \; a(g) = g\}|}{2|G|}.$$ However this is clearly not enough to prove the statement.

[This question was already asked by me on MSE, but received no answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3328203/407165)

Also, if we restrict the question to abelian case, then the statement will be true. It was proved by Gary Sherman in "What is the Probability an Automorphism Fixes a Group Element?"

Comment: A strategy that occurs to me: try to bound $af(G)$ in group extensions, which reduces the problem to finite simple groups.

Comment: Is it possible (or easy) to make this a question about $Aut(G) \ltimes G$, and then prove the corresponding statement for arbitrary groups?

Comment: I had the same idea as @user44191 - using your notation in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347377/erdos-turan-theorem-for-normal-subgroups/3347470#3347470) I believe you can show that $af(G)=cf(G,G\rtimes Aut(G))$ and using a result that $|Aut(G)|\to\infty$ and $|G|\to\infty$ I think you can show for any $\epsilon>0$ that $af(G)\le \epsilon+\frac{1}{2}$ for large enough $|G|$, but I haven't been able to improve on that.

Comment: Can you do virtually abelian groups?

Answer (score 9):

This statement becomes correct when restricted to groups $G$ with trivial Fitting subgroup (ie with $F(G) = 1$), but at present I don't know how to prove it in general. The quantity $af(G)$ you consider is the number of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ orbits on $G$ divided by $|G|$.

When $Z(G) = 1$, $G \cong {\rm Inn}(G)$ embeds isomorphically into ${\rm Aut}(G)$, as a normal subgroup. In that case, your quantity $af(G)$ is certainly at most $\frac{k(G)}{|G|}$, where $k(G)$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. The ratio $\frac{k(G)}{|G|}$ is the commuting probability of $G$. In the case that $F(G) = 1,$ Bob Guralnick and I proved that the commuting probability tends to zero as $|G| \to \infty$ (this does not require CFSG, though the convergence rate can be shown to be much faster using CFSG. There is also a more elementary proof of that fact due to P.M. Neumann, of which Guralnick and  I were unaware at the time).

Later edit: Perhaps it would have been better to say at the beginning that it is true that ${\rm af}(G) \to 0$ as $[G:F(G)] \to \infty$, which is really what the quoted results imply.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible road map to a solution. Let $G$ be a finite group such that $\def\af{\operatorname{af}}\def\Aut{\operatorname{Aut}}$$\af(G)$ is bounded away from $0$. We want to show that $|G|$ is bounded. By the theorem of Peter Neumann that Geoff Robinson mentioned, $G$ is bounded-by-abelian-by-bounded. In fact, $G$ has a bounded-index $2$-step nilpotent normal subgroup $H$ such that $|H'|$ is bounded. We can moreover assume that every $h \in H$ has a bounded-size $\Aut G$-orbit.

This almost reduces us to considering $H$ in place of $G$, except that automorphisms of $H$ need not extend to automorphisms of $G$. In any case, $G = H$ is an excellent model problem (i.e., $2$-step nilpotent with bounded commutator). These groups tend to have loads of outer automorphisms, so $H$ should have plenty of large $\Aut H$-orbits. (The archetypal example here is the extraspecial $p$-group of order $p^{2n+1}$ and exponent $p$, which has outer automorphism group containing $\operatorname{Sp}(2n, p)$.)

Finally we have an extension problem. Given that $H$ has bounded index in $G$, we need to show that at least one of the large $\Aut H$-orbits contains a large $\Aut G$-orbit. For example, what if $G$ is virtually abelian? (Split extensions such as a dihedral group are not interesting, because it's easy to extend automorphisms in that case.)